# How to remove multiple viewcontrollers from UITabBarController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to remove two view controllers from a tab bar controller, it's crashing the application.

Removing one controller is easily done

```
let index = 0 //0 to 5
        viewControllers?.remove(at: index)
```

But when i try to remove more than one, application crash. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Could you share the error you're receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are removing them from index 0...5, then the indices will no longer correct after removing the first item and you would eventually get an index out of range exception. Something you could do would be to remove them starting with the greatest index and going down to zero (5...0).

As pointed out below, if all you want to do is removed the first five, you could simply call `viewControllers?.removeFirst(5)`.

Comment: Yep, you're right that is a more direct approach. My answer was trying to illustrate why the crash was occurring. I'll update to not put forth that this is the easiest way to go.